# Create and edit form dynamic input text boxes values using FormArray/FormGroup? With reactive forms in angular

Tags: typescript, angular7, reactive

In my angular 7 app, I need to implement functionality populate input text boxes dynamically in form and need to create/edit values to API.
I am done with populating input text boxes dynamically in angular form. Now I need to do create and edit with those fields.can you please suggest how to do that ? In Angular7.

Use case eg : 
 I have a languages array object with id and name eg. Languages=[{1,En}, {2, Fr}...] Receiving from api. Now first step i need to populate input text boxes for those languages with language name as label for each text box using FormArray/ FormGroup  angular form directives.. to create and edit values entered in those text boxes .need to implement save functionality..

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to create a json object to post to API using the data from the angular FormGroup. You can check out myform.value or myform.getRawValue().

Comment: Thanks for your reply Teja, I have a languages array object with id and name eg. Languages=[{1,En}, {2, Fr}...] Receiving from api. Now first step i need to populate input text boxes for those languages with language name as label for each text box using FormArray/ FormGroup  angular form directives.. to create and edit values entered in those text boxes .need to implement save functionality..

Answer (score 0):

If you are having an object that is being returned by an API, and want to prepopulate those values into your formarray, then you must create a dynamic form array inside a form group and iterate over the object you've received and assign the required values to the formcontrols inside that formarray.

*Would have been good if you had posted the code what you've tried.*
I've just created a sample object and a formarray.

**In .ts file**

```
export class XYZ {
    Languages = [{ Id: 1, lang: "english" }, { Is: 2, lang: "French" };]
    dynamic: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.dynamic = this.fb.group({
        Langs: this.fb.array([])
    });

    for (let x in this.Languages) {
        this.filtersFormArray.push(this.createFilterGroup(this.Languages[x].lang));
    }

    createFilterGroup(text) {
        return this.fb.group({
            displayText: [text]
        });

    }
    get filtersFormArray() {
        return (<FormArray>this.dynamic.get('Langs'));
    }
}
savelangs() {
    console.log(this.dynamic.value)
}
}
```

**In .html file**

```
<div formArrayName="Langs">
    <div *ngFor="let filter of filtersFormArray.controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-form-field>
                <textarea matInput formControlName="displayText"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button (click)="savelangs()">Save </button>
```

You can edit the values also and when save button is clicked, the new values are printed in the console.